# Are "Make it Rain" and faerie chests affected by +gold artifacts? Which ones?

Tags: tap-titans

After getting quite some artifacts and leveling them, I checked on "Make it Rain" perk (had one free from daily dungeon) to help me get past a wall.

To my surprise, it was giving me very little gold, around the same I could get out of a chesterton. I remember using it at the beginning of the game (to push for the very first prestige) and it was a insurmountable amount of gold. The same with faerie chests. I usually can make more gold in the time it takes to watch an ad than what is offered for watching the ad.

It made me wonder if artifacts with +gold are not affecting it.

I have:

- Future's Fortune lv 30
- Chest of Contentment lv 20
- Crafter's Elixir lv 50

And several other non-gold related artifacts.

Is it correct that make it rain is not scaling together with the artifacts?

Comment: I think in TT1 they don't scale but I am not sure. In TT2 they do scale and you even have a Fairy Gold artifact for example